# remove duplicate labels in geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like:

```
composerName             season Location Time Venue eventType id conductorName interval movement workTitle
1 Anthem,                 1918-19       55   55    55        55 55            55       55       55        55
2 Beethoven,  Ludwig  van 1912-13       37   37    37        37 37            37       37       37        37
3 Beethoven,  Ludwig  van 1915-16       38   38    38        38 38            38       38       38        38
4 Beethoven,  Ludwig  van 1919-20       38   38    38        38 38            38       38       38        38
5 Beethoven,  Ludwig  van 1920-21       36   36    36        36 36            36       36       36        36
6 Beethoven,  Ludwig  van 1921-22       44   44    44        44 44            44       44       44        44
```

My code looks like this:

```
ggplot(aes(x = composerName, y = id, fill = season, label = composerName), data = music)+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  geom_text(angle = 90, position = position_dodge(width = 1), hjust = -.1)
```

Which gives this:

[image]

I'd like it to include only one label per composer rather than a label for each season. How do I remove the duplicate labels?

Comment: Create a new data.frame where you have one label per composer and pass that to `geom_text(data = ...)`.

Comment: E.g. `geom_text(data = dplyr::distinct(music, composerName))` should work. Also you can use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: @Axeman that gives me `Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?`.

Comment: Yeah, think that over for a second.. What is the error telling you? Hint: I did not give you a complete working piece of code. :)

Comment: I can't show you how to do it because that data is not enough to make your plot, nor is it easy to copy with all those spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: I needed to include `stat = 'identity'` in `geom_text()`:

```
ggplot(aes(x = composerName, y = id, fill = season, label = composerName), data = music)+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  geom_text(stat = 'identity', angle = 90, 
            position = 'identity', hjust = -.2, check_overlap = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: it does not solve the issue.

Comment: check_overlap = TRUE
only because of this line and having overlaps you managed to get rid of them. also, angel = 90 helped for having overlaps.